# SSM Automation Run Command is not longer than default 3600 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-ssm

I have been working with AWS Systems Manager and I have created a Document to run a command, But it appears there is no way to overwrite the timeout for a run command in an SSM

I have changed the execution timeout here in the parameters but does not work.
[image]

also, I added a timeoutSeconds in my Document and it doesn't work either.

This is my Document (I'm using schema version 2.2):

```
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Runs a Python command"
parameters:
  Params:
    type: "String"
    description: "Params after the python3 keyword."
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runShellScript"
  name: "Python3"
  inputs:
    timeoutSeconds: '300000'
    runCommand:
      - "sudo /usr/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/{{Params}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

**1:** The setting that’s displayed in your screenshot in the **Other parameters** section is the **Delivery Timeout**, which is different from the execution timeout.

You must specify the execution timeout value in the **Execution Timeout** field, if available. Not all SSM documents require that you specify an execution timeout. If a Systems Manager document doesn't require that you explicitly specify an execution timeout value, then Systems Manager enforces the hard-coded default execution timeout.

**2:** In your document, the `timeoutSeconds` attribute is in the wrong place. It needs to be on the same level as the `action`.

```
...
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runShellScript"
  timeoutSeconds: 300000
  name: "Python3"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - "sudo /usr/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/{{Params}}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but  timeoutSeconds is in the right place 
according to schemaVersion: '2.2' also with the default Delivery Timeout doesn't work either :| 


https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    timeoutSeconds: '300000'
```

Isn't this string but not integer?